# What are the Jordanian visa rules for travellers entering from Israel?

Tags: visas, israel, jordan

Could someone please explain Visa regulations for Jordan, they seem to differ in terms of cost & requirements depending on how and where you enter the country and how long you are staying.

Comment: My notes from a couple years ago for the border at Aqaba are "Visa fees are 10 JD / $14 for single entry; open Sun – Thurs 06:30hrs – 22:00hrs and Fri – Sat 0800hrs – 20:00hrs" They've probably changed since then though.

Answer (score 9):

Here are my [notes](http://nibot.livejournal.com/12980.html) from July 2002:

> The Jordanian Embassy in Tel Aviv is located on the tenth floor of the highrise "Beit Oz" (home of Oz Investments Ltd) at 14 Abba Hillel Silver Street, phone 03-751-7722. Single-entry, 3-month visas are 88 shekels for all nationalities and NIS 168 gets you a 6-month multiple-entry visa. The consular department is open weekdays (Sun-Thu) 09:00 to 12:30. A passport sized photo is required for the application and we were directed to a photo shop two blocks away where 8 passport-style photos were printed up for NIS 20. Avoid bringing any bags, backpacks, etc to accelerate the security screenings.

Americans and Canadians can get visas without any trouble, but our Serbian friend was denied a visa on the spot with no explanation.

We took the Egg'd bus to Jerusalem, walked across to East Jerusalem and caught an Arab shared taxi from Damascus Gate which took us across the Palestinian Territory and through Jericho to the Allenby / King Hussein bridge.   Here there is a bus which takes you through the short no-man's-land to the Jordanian border crossing.  (All of this was accurately detailed in the Lonely Planet guidebook.)

It look a little while at the border (2 hours) but we had no real trouble.

At that time there were very few foreigners crossing the border there.